# Load datastore Extjs specifying proxy dynamically

Tags: java, servlets, extjs

I am new to ExtJs. I am developing a web application using `JSP`. In that, have a `servlet` called `ShowProductInferenceServlet`. When i access the `servlet` using an `AJAX` call, it returns a response just fine. Here is the `AJAX` call using `jQuery`.

```
$.get("ShowProductInferenceServlet", {
                                    levelFlag : levelFlag,
                                    level1 : selectedCategory,
                                    level2 : selectedSubCategory,
                                    level3 : selectedProductName,
                                    level4 : selectedMaxQty,
                                }, function(responseText){
                                    alert("Shown Inference : " + responseText);
                                });
```

Now that the `servlet` is working fine, i want to populate a `datastore` using the response from the `servlet`. I am creating the `proxy` for the `datastore` dynamically as there are other `servlets` using the same database and i encounter locking issues if i declare the `proxy` for the `datastore` beforehand. Here is the code i used for the `datastore`.

```
var dataStorePrimaryInferences = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId : 'dataStorePrimaryInferences',
        fields : [ 'code', 'text', 'confidence' ],
        autoLoad : false,
        proxy : {
            listeners : {
                exception : function(proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
                    console.log('exception' + response.responseText);
                }
            }
        },
    });
```

Here is the code for the dynamic assignment of `proxy` and related details.

```
dataStorePrimaryInferences.getProxy.type = 'ajax';
dataStorePrimaryInferences.getProxy.url = 'ShowProductInferenceServlet';
dataStorePrimaryInferences.getProxy().getReader().type = 'json';
dataStorePrimaryInferences.getProxy().getReader().root = 'result';
dataStorePrimaryInferences.getProxy().setExtraParam("levelFlag", levelFlag);
dataStorePrimaryInferences.getProxy().setExtraParam("level1", selectedCategory);
dataStorePrimaryInferences.getProxy().setExtraParam("level2", selectedSubCategory);
dataStorePrimaryInferences.getProxy().setExtraParam("level3", selectedProductName);
dataStorePrimaryInferences.getProxy().setExtraParam("level4", selectedMaxQty);
dataStorePrimaryInferences.load();
```

When i run the program, i get this error in the web console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

The trace of the error seems to be pointing to the `load()`. Can someone tell me where am wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your json response look like?

Comment: Plz check the exact response you get and update your post with it

Comment: Can you see the network request being made to ShowProductInferenceServlet? Also, for the proxy you should be using setUrl() and not the .url way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's because of the way you're setting your proxy. Perhaps you should set it all in one go, like so:

```
dataStorePrimaryInferences.setProxy({
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'ShowProductInferenceServlet',
    reader: 'json',
    root: 'result',
    extraParams: {
        levelFlag: levelFlag,
        level1: selectedCategory,
        level2: selectedSubCategory,
        level3: selectedProductName,
        level4: selectedMaxQty
    }
});
```